# Guide for beginner in shaders

Tags: unity, opengl, shaders, directx

first of all i know nothing about opengl or shaders and now tried to learn but im stuck little bit,
I've downloaded some shader tutorials from unity learning center but i can't completely understand what is happening in the codes i know C++ and C# learnt the syntax of shaderlabs but still i cant really understand what is happening in codes and i can't write something that is in my mind i can only write the things that someone taught me and even i don't know why but shading section in unity documentation is little hard to understand for me  so i've been researching recently and found GLSL ,

now i have some questions:

1: Do i have to learn opengl or DirectX for better understanding and writing shaders in unity or even UDK?

2: if its not important to learn opengl should i learn GLSL?

3: overall im little confused about shaders they say unity shaderlabs is based on CGFX from nvidia should i learn this one?

if you give me a good guide for shaders i will be grateful i just dont know where to start,
Note: i cant really buy a E-Book or something its not available here so i have to use free ones.

Comment: Please read through the help center. As you'll see there, questions on How to get started aren't good for asking here, since this isn't a forum. Help Center Link: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help

Comment: Requests for guides or how to get started don't really fit our Q&A format here well. You can try asking on a discussion forum like GameDev.net or in [chat], or really just google for shader tutorials - there are lots out there. As just one example, [here's a cheat sheet I drew up as a companion for a workshop I taught on Unity shaders](http://dmgregory.ca/misc/shadercheatsheet.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on why you want to learn about shaders.

- Are you going to use Unity? Then learn Unity's system.
- If you want to learn to use OpenGL, then learn about GLSL.

If you are confused about shaders in general, try to learn more about the graphics pipeline and how shaders fit into it.

This could be useful if you are going to use OpenGL:

- https://learnopengl.com/#!Introduction